# How to make a 'group by' on a Child's property and avoiding a 'NotSupportedException'

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I try to get the count of loan by Book Type.

i have these 3  class (Simplified). part of a Code-first Model :

```
 public class Loan
   {
      public int LoanId {get;set;}
      .....
      public int BookId {get;set;}
      Public virtual Book {get;set;}

   }

    //Book parent class
    public class Book {
    public int BookId {get;set;}
    ...
    }

    //a Book child class with a specific 'Type' property
    public SmallBook : Book 
    {
     public string Type {get;set;} 
     ...
    }
```

So long, i tried this kind of Query ....

```
   var StatsMono = (from p in context.Loans
         //the 'where' clause allow to obtain all the loans where Loans.Book is a SmallBook.
         where context.Books.OfType<SmallBook>().Any(exm => exm.BookId == p.BookId)
         //here is my problem : i can't access 'SmallBook.Type' w/o cast
         group p by ((SmallBook)p.Book).Type into g
         select { GroupingElement=g.Key,intValue=g.Count()}
         ).ToList();
```

...but i can't get rid of the following exception:

> Unable to cast the type 'Ips.Models.Book' to type
>   'Ips.Models.SmallBook'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM
>   primitive or enumeration types.

**I understand why i get this error but now i'm wondering if there is a way to achieve what i want with only one query ?**

Comment: @AlperTungaArslan that the way i run Non-polymorphic Querie in order to get SmallBooks entities. Anyway it won't change anything, because exm is a SmallBook entity in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use explicit join:

```
var StatsMono = (from p in db.Loans
                 join b in db.Books.OfType<SmallBook>() on p.BookId equals b.BookId
                 group p by b.Type into g
                 select new { GroupingElement = g.Key, intValue = g.Count() }
       ).ToList();
```

But better add the inverse navigation property to your model

```
public abstract class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    // ...
    public ICollection<Loan> Loans { get; set; }
}
```

and use it

```
var StatsMono = (from b in db.Books.OfType<SmallBook>()
                 from p in b.Loans
                 group p by b.Type into g
                 select new { GroupingElement = g.Key, intValue = g.Count() }
       ).ToList();
```

Comment: Ouch ! i didn't thought about a join... It works perfectly thanks ! I'll consider using inverse navigation property but i have to be sure i won't get Json/Serialization circular references.

Answer (score 0):

Something like..

```
var result = context.Loans.GroupBy(g=> g.book.Type).select(s=> new { BookType= s.book.type, count = s.count }).ToList();
```

Comment: it won't work since there is no property 'Type' in Book.